# how to read lines with irreguar number of records line by line in fortran

Tags: file, csv, fortran

I have test.csv (300 lines) file as below

```
10 20 100 2 5 4 5 7 9 10 ....
55 600 7000 500 25 
3 10
2 5 6
....
```

Each line has different number of integers (maximum number of records =1000) and I need to proceed these records line by line. I tried as below

```
integer,dimension(1000)::rec
integer::i,j
open(unit=5,file="test.csv",status="old",action="read")
do i=1,300
read(unit=5,fmt=*) (rec(j),j=1,1000)
!do some procedue with rec
enddo
close(unit=50)
```

but it seems like that `rec` array is not constructed by line by line. It means that when i=n, `rec` get the numbers from non-nth line. How can I solve this problem.

thank you

Comment: Try to use another unit number (greater than 10 for example), 5 is reserved for keyboard input. By the way, you are opening unit 5 and closing 50

Answer (score 1):

List directed formatting (as specified by the star in the read statement) reads what it needs to satisfy the list (hence it is "list directed").  As shown, your code will try and read 1000 values each iteration, consuming as many records (lines) as required each iteration in order to do that.

(List directed formatting has a number of surprising features beyond that, which may have made sense with card based input forms 40 years ago, but are probably misplaced today.  Before using list directed input you should understand exactly what the rules around it say.)

A realistic and robust approach to this sort of situation is to read in the input line by line, then "manually" process each line, tokenising that line and extracting values as per whatever rules you are following.

(You should get in touch with whoever is naming files that have absolutely no commas or semicolons with an extension ".csv", and have a bit of a chat.)

(As a general rule, low value unit numbers are to be avoided.  Due to historical reasons they may have been preconnected for other purposes.  Reconnecting them to a different file is guaranteed to work for that specific purpose, but other statements in your program may implicitly be assuming that the low value unit is still connected as it was before the program started executing - for example, PRINT and READ statements intended to work with the console might start operating on your file instead.)